# fetch results as we type in a text area, in an asynchronous, rate-limited manner

Tags: jquery

I enter text in a text field, the page fetches results from a remote source. And its rate-limited, it waits 250 milliseconds even if we type rapidly. And it must not block user input as we type.

I recall seeing a Jquery plugin that can wrap keyups and screen resizes and waits for a delay/ In case of resize, it noted just 10 events even when the browser threw 100s of events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like using a debounce function could be the type of behavior you are looking for:

http://underscorejs.org/#debounce

For a search control -  you could bind your debounce function to the onkeyup event of your search text box.

```
Pseudocode:

var listener = _.debounce(searchListener, 250);
$control.keyup(listener);
```

Comment: I chose the throttle functionality of http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce/examples/debounce/